# How to add a <td> tag to ListViewItem?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, listview

I want to implement an apperance as [this article](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html) mentioned using nested ListView control. However, in my scenario, I cannot use EntityDataSource control so I bind data manually.

My table:

```
Categories
  PK: UniqueId, Guid
  Name, string
  ParentId, Guid

<asp:ListView ID="CategoryList" runat="server" 
        onitemdatabound="CategoryList_ItemDataBound">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (PractiseEntities context = new PractiseEntities()) {
        var result = from categories in context.Categories
                     select categories;
        CategoryList.DataSource = result;
        CategoryList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I want the sub category have an indent by add a `<td>` tag to the item which "ParentId" is not null. And my question is how to edit the generated html tags in the ItemDataBound event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have something like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><%# GetParentContent(Eval("ParentID")) %></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

in the code-behind:

```
protected string GetParentContent(object ParentID)
{
    if(ParentID!=null)
        ... return parent HTML ...
    else
        return "";
}
```